# An injection from R × {0, 1} to R

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

What would be an example of this 
An injection from R × {0, 1} to R

i think it is all real numbers f(x) = x

Can some one help me on this.  Thanks in advance

Comment: Your function is not defined as a function from your domain. You omit the interval (or perhaps you mean pair of points?) $\{0, 1\}$.

Answer (score 7):

HINT: Start by finding an injection $f$ from $\Bbb R$ to the set of positive real numbers. Then the map

$$g:\Bbb R\times\{0,1\}\to\Bbb R:\langle x,i\rangle\mapsto\begin{cases}
f(x),&\text{if }i=0\\
-f(x),&\text{if }i=1
\end{cases}$$

is an injection. For $f$ consider an exponential function.

Answer (score 2):

$$f(x,y)=\arctan(x)+\pi y ...$$